# how to bend the plane?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm new to blender, I want to add some bend to my plane I have extruded some faces of a plane which has been subdivided earlier when I applied simple deform I can see the extruding part is bending but not the plane. how can I able to get rid of this problem
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you use an *Empty* as origin.

- To bend the plane, you need to use it's own origin.
- You can use two modifiers, one using the empty, other bending the plane

[image]

Comment: i have done that too but its doin the same

Comment: Hey :). You can see from the gif, it works differently. You'll need to provide more details if you want help.