# why i cant bent my plane?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I want to bend my plane in y-axis but it's not happening. I have been facing this problem from many days
[image]

Comment: yeah I have subdivided the plane too but I'm not able to bend it

Comment: Is this different from your [other](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/174078/how-to-bend-the-plane) question?

Comment: Probably confusing global and local object axis, have you tried the other axises in the modifier panel?

Comment: yeah I have other axes it's working with the x-axis but it's not bending on neither y nor z

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple deform modifier is sometimes... not very intuitive.

- You need to rotate the *origin point* by 90 degrees, so that all axis work
- Check *Tool > Transform > Origins* and use the *Rotate tool*. Then uncheck.
- When using an *Empty* as origin, the same rule applies.

I'm not sure why it works like this :).

[image]