# Why is it that sometimes the bend modifier bends in two different directions while other times it works as intended?

Tags: modeling

Sorry for unclear question, but the Simple Deform modifier has been one of the most difficult ones to use consistenly. It sometimes does what I intend it to:

[image]

while other times this happens:

[image]

Transforms are applied, everything else seems to be fine, and the two objects have basically the same topology, so what causes this difference? Also tried using an empty for the Axis Origin of the 2nd result, but to no avail. If anyone could give me a quick rundown of why this happens and how to use the Simple Deform modofier properly, it would be greatly appreciated. At the moment whether it works as intended or not feels like a gamble.

Comment: Hey :). This thread could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/174599/

Comment: @weittakes Hello and welcome. Don't just add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted